# Import maven project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-studio

I have a very complex maven project in Eclipse with many modules and submodules and a lot of dependencies to each other and to third party files in pom.xml files.
 It works well in net browsers. 
But how can I try it in PC within an Android phone emulator? 
 I have found this Android Studio program, but how can I import my very complex maven project from Eclipse without adding extra file(s) to it (like AndroidManifest.xml,etc) and not to destroy the original structure of the project?
Anyway, I could use the File/Open option from menu and I can see the project in AS, but I can't run it.
 What should I do to run?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to migrate an Android application from Eclipse IDE to Android Studio, then the hard truth is there is no easy way. I know because I already did this and it was worth the move.

And if you decide to take the hard route you will need to fully understand the directory structure of your Eclipse project compared to the directory structure of Android Studio projects and how the two IDEs build and deploy the project - because they are totally different and Android Studio uses gradle for its build.

Try reading through the [Android Studio Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes) and the [Migrate to Android Studio from Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html).